# weighing avg by columns vs rows outputs different results

Tags: average, data-analysis

First of all, I just know the basics of math, so please be patient.

I have an overall score for a company with the product1 and product2. However when I do the overall for each criteria like `A, B, C, D, E,` the sum of these criteria is not equal to the overall score.

*Example A*

**Data**

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\;&A&B&C&D&E\\
\hline
\text{product1}&1&2&3&4&5\\
\text{product2}&2&2&3&3&3
\end{array}$

**Weighing**

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\;&AA&BB&CC&DD&EE\\
\hline
\text{product1}&2&3&2&3&5\\
\text{product2}&2&4&3&3&4
\end{array}$

Formula for row $i$: $(A_i \times AA_i + B_i \times BB_i + \dots ) /sum(AA_i:EE_i)$

> product1: $\dfrac{2+6+6+12+25}{15}=3.4$
>
> product2: $\dfrac{4+8+9+9+12}{16}=2.625$
>
> Total AVG: $\dfrac{3.4+2.625}{2}=3.0125$

---

If I try to find what is the weighing avg for each column, the total is different. Both examples should output the same weighing avg? If not, why? What is the most adequate way to represent the avg for this type of need? the first example or the second?

*Example B*

Formula for column $J$: $(J_1 \times JJ_1 + J_2 \times JJ_2)/sum(JJ_1:JJ_2)$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\;&A&B&C&D&E\\
\hline
\text{average}&\dfrac{2+4}{6}=1.5
&\dfrac{6+8}{7}=2
&\dfrac{6+9}{5}=3
&\dfrac{12+9}{6}=3.5
&\dfrac{25+12}{9}=4.111
\end{array}$

> Total AVG: $\dfrac{1.5+2+3+3.5+4.111}{5}=2.822$

Answer (score 1):

Your $2.8$ is not correct.  If you do the weighted average of $1,5\ \   2 \ \   3 \ \  3,5\ \   4$ with the weights you are using you get $3.0333333$

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand what you mean. I am using the weights as you can see in the second formula. `(A1 * AA1 + A2 * AA2) / sum(AA1:AA2)`

Comment: Those give you the third line nicely.  Then when you weight the third line by the five weights $2,2,3,3,3$ you get $3.0333333$

Comment: sorry, but still not understanding. I would appreciate an example of what you are saying. I don't have  five weights. I have  five weights per product.

Comment: I just did $\frac {2 \cdot 1.5 + 2\cdot 2 +3 \cdot 3 + e \cdot 3.5 + 3 \cdot 4}{2+2+3+3+3}=3.033333$  That is the same weighting you were doing before.

Comment: 2,2,3,3,3 are the values for the product2. for product1 we have 1,2,3,4,5, so, i don't get what you are saying. for a bounty i am expecting a more complete information/example than this. thanks anyway.

Comment: You were weighting each product by the same weightings.  I reproduced your 3.4 and 2.6667.  Then when you averaged the two in example B I assumed you wanted to weight the averages the same way.  If you don't weight them the same way, why would you expect the same average?  That is why you get 2.8-you don't apply your weighting factors and the last ratings are higher.

Comment: I think the problem is that when you averaged vertically the weightings don't matter, as they apply equally to each row.  It appears you thought they were incorporated at that step, so should not be applied when you average horizontally.  In fact, the weightings are horizontal, so should be applied in that direction.  Note that if you change the weightings, the bottom line in Example B does not change.  That emphasizes that the weightings must be applied in the horizontal direction.

Comment: After some tests I find the same conclusion. However, in the second example, I can do the arithmetic average, and then, multiply the result by the weighting. Something like this for column A. ((1+2) / 2)*2/4

Answer (score 1):

The two methods are fundamentally different, and so in general will produce different results.

The row average of row $i$ is:

$$\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{N_c} {e_{ij}\times w_{ij}}}{\sum_{j=1}^{N_c} w_{ij}}$$

where $N_c$ is the number of columns, $e_{ij}$ is the entry in the $j$-th column of the $i$-th row in the data table, and $w_{ij}$ is the entry in the $j$-th column of the $i$-th row in the weighings table.

The column average of column $j$ is:

$$\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N_r} {e_{ij}\times w_{ij}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N_r} w_{ij}}$$

where $N_r$ is the number of rows.

To see why the two are not equal, consider simpler tables:

**DATA**

$$\begin{array} {c|cc}
\;&A&B\\
\hline
prod1&a&b\\
prod2&c&d
\end{array}$$

**WEIGHINGS**

$$\begin{array} {c|cc}
\;&A&B\\
\hline
prod1&e&f\\
prod2&g&h
\end{array}$$

The row average is $\left(\dfrac{ae+bf}{e+f}+\dfrac{cg+dh}{g+h}\right)/2$.

The column average is $\left(\dfrac{ae+cg}{e+g}+\dfrac{bf+dh}{f+h}\right)/2$.

You need some maths to prove that these are rarely equal, but they are indeed rarely equal.

As to your question as to which to use, they have different meanings. The row average tests a product against a set of criteria. The column average tests a criteria against a set of products. So they both have a purpose.